# Query about memory management in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have query regarding memory management for iPhone app.

I have a app in which is also build in for android app as well.

Now we have same functinality and same variables but due to some bad memory management the app gets crashed for iPhone (after 20 - 25 min) and on Android it works perfectly for much longer time without crashing.

In android they have garbage collector but for iPhone sdk we dont have anything like that, so I'm a bit confuse how to proceed.

I have released all the memory allocations in didReceiveMemoryWarning and also in dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt you have to find the memory leak. so run the app in debug mode or using instrument first find the problem and update here. and important thing if you get EXC_Bad_Acc means you have to enabled NSZombieEnabled for further detail give me a comment

Answer (score 1):

Before you do what @maheswaran suggests, run the analyzer to determine if you have any easy to find (for the analyzer) memory problems.

Also, it would be good for you to put some time aside and read about how memory management works on iOS.